# Dynamically add multiple input fields to a form with ionic/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue adding multiple input fields to a form. I followed [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/dynamic-infinite-input-fields-in-an-ionic-application/) example but I'm facing problems with more than one input field.
Any advice?

My form input

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                 <form [formGroup]="slideThreeForm" class="ion-padding ion-margin">

                    <ion-item *ngFor="let control of slideThreeForm.controls | keyvalue">
                    <ion-input required type="text" [formControlName]="control.key" placeHolder="Name"></ion-input>
                    <ion-input required type="text" [formControlName]="control.key" placeHolder="Price"></ion-input>
                    <ion-input required type="number" [formControlName]="control.key" placeHolder="Quantity"></ion-input>
                    <ion-icon (click)="removeControl(control)" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-item>

                 </form>
                    <ion-button expand="full" color="light" (click)="addControl()">Add Item</ion-button>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
</ion-list>
```

page.ts

```
export class ModalSlidePage  {
@ViewChild('quoteSlider') quoteSlider;

public slideOneForm: FormGroup;
public slideTwoForm: FormGroup;
public slideThreeForm: FormGroup;
private itemCount: number = 1;


public submitAttempt: boolean = false;

modalTitle:string;

constructor(
  private modalController: ModalController,
  public formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {
  this.slideOneForm = formBuilder.group({
  companyName: [''],
  quoteType: [''],
  quoteDueDate: ['']
});

this.slideTwoForm = formBuilder.group({
  companyAddress: [''],
  clientAddress: [''],
  comments: ['']
});

this.slideThreeForm = formBuilder.group({
  item1: ['']
  });
 }


async closeModal() {
const onCloseData: string = "Wrapped Up!";
await this.modalController.dismiss(onCloseData);
}

addControl(){
this.itemCount++;
this.slideThreeForm.addControl('item' + this.itemCount, new 
FormControl(''));
 }

removeControl(control){
this.slideThreeForm.removeControl(control.key);
}
```

Right now only one value is returned on addControl. I need to display all three values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you mean by "I need to display all three values". Can you clarify? Also, does it work if you comment out `this.slideOneForm` and `this.slideTwoForm`?

Comment: What I mean is that I need three input values to be submitted, right now it only submits one value. It does work if I comment out slideOneForm and slideTwoForm

Answer (score 0):

You are currently repeating the same formControlName for each input. I'm not sure whether this exact syntax will work for dynamic formControlNames, but this will explain the idea:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let control of slideThreeForm.controls | keyvalue">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ control.key }} Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input required type="text" formControlName="{{ control.key }}_name" placeHolder="Name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ control.key }} Price</ion-label>
    <ion-input required type="text" formControlName="{{ control.key }}_price" placeHolder="Price"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{ control.key }} Quantity</ion-label>
    <ion-input required type="number" formControlName="{{ control.key }}_quantity" placeHolder="Quantity"></ion-input><ion-icon (click)="removeControl(control)" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the feedback Ben Hulan, I'll give it another go.